# Is this (Lock-Free) Queue Implementation Thread-Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

I am trying to create a lock-free queue implementation in Java, mainly for personal learning. The queue should be a general one, allowing any number of readers and/or writers concurrently.

Would you please review it, and suggest any improvements/issues you find?

Thank you.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class LockFreeQueue<T> {
    private static class Node<E> {
        E value;
        volatile Node<E> next;

        Node(E value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private AtomicReference<Node<T>> head, tail;

    public LockFreeQueue() {
        // have both head and tail point to a dummy node
        Node<T> dummyNode = new Node<T>(null);
        head = new AtomicReference<Node<T>>(dummyNode);
        tail = new AtomicReference<Node<T>>(dummyNode);
    }

    /**
     * Puts an object at the end of the queue.
     */
    public void putObject(T value) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(value);
        Node<T> prevTailNode = tail.getAndSet(newNode);
        prevTailNode.next = newNode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets an object from the beginning of the queue. The object is removed
     * from the queue. If there are no objects in the queue, returns null.
     */
    public T getObject() {
        Node<T> headNode, valueNode;

        // move head node to the next node using atomic semantics
        // as long as next node is not null
        do {
            headNode = head.get();
            valueNode = headNode.next;
            // try until the whole loop executes pseudo-atomically
            // (i.e. unaffected by modifications done by other threads)
        } while (valueNode != null && !head.compareAndSet(headNode, valueNode));

        T value = (valueNode != null ? valueNode.value : null);

        // release the value pointed to by head, keeping the head node dummy
        if (valueNode != null)
            valueNode.value = null;

        return value;
}
```

Comment: Ported to Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224/is-this-lock-free-queue-implementation-thread-safe

Answer (score 4):

The code is not thread-safe.  Consider `putObject(...)`:

```
public void putObject(T value) {
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(value);
    Node<T> prevTailNode = tail.getAndSet(newNode);
    prevTailNode.next = newNode;
}
```

The 2nd statement adds the new node before the previous node's `next` pointer has been set.  That only happens in the 3rd statement.  Thus, there is a window in which the `next` is `null`; i.e. a race condition.

Even if you fixed that, there is a more insidious problem.  A thread reading the `next` field for an Node object won't *necessarily* see the value that a second thread has just written.  That's a consequence of the Java memory model.  In this case, the way to *ensure* that the following read always sees the earlier written value is to either:

- declare `next` to be `volatile`, or
- do both the reading and writing in a primitive mutex on the same object.

EDIT: on reading the code for `getObject()` and `putObject()` in more detail, I can see that nothing forces the non-null value of `next` to be flushed to memory in `putObject`, and nothing forces `getObject` to read `next` from main memory.  So the `getObject` code could see the wrong value of `next`, causing it to return `null` when there is really an element in the queue.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong with next being null. Actually, tail.next is always null, and it doesn't make any problem. If next is null in getObject, the loop terminates and null is returned (queue is empty). Also, the loop in getObject can spin only if another thread has written head successfully - eg. the other thread succeeded, which is what we want from lock-free algorithms.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still incorrect, in many areas (the whole EDIT2, for instance, indicates you haven't noticed the queue always contains at least one, dummy node).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated my code to make `next` volatile, and renamed `nextNode` to `valueNode` in `getObject()` to make its purpose clearer. But I guess that reading a stale value in the reader thread doesn't make the code "not thread-safe"; it's just a performance issue, right?

Comment: @Hosam - No.  I think that `getObject()` can return `null` when there is really an element in the queue.  In fact, it can do it repeatedly.

Comment: @Stephen C: Yes, it can, but this only delays processing of that element. I guess it depends on how we view it, whether the availability of an item in the queue is required *immediately* or can be received later on. I have fixed it anyway (I think), so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Hosam - 1) it is theoretically possible that a particular thread would have *always* seen a stale value of next when it calls `getObject()`. 2) I would say that a `getObject()` method that occasionally returned `null` for a non-empty queue violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @Stephen: You're right. That's certainly true. Do you have any other suggestions or notes about the code?

Answer (score 1):

I see only two problems with your code:

- one is the problem with memory operations ordering Stephen C mentioned (can be solved by declaring `next` and `value` `volatile`) (Node: value has the same problem)
- second is a more subtle one, and not concurrency related: after you return an object in `getObject`, you still retain its reference from head. This could lead to a memory leak.

Otherwise the algorithm is OK. A vague demonstration (assume the above are fixed):

L1: `tail` can never be deleted from the queue. This holds because when something is stored in `tail`, it has `next == null`. Also, when you assign something to `xxx.next` (only in `putObject`), it cannot be `tail`, because of the getAndSet's atomicity and the ordering between volatile write and subsequent read - assume you read a non-null `tail.next`, this value must have been written by `putObject` and therefore *happens-after* the last line of it. This means it *happens-after* the previous line, which means the value we are reading is not from `tail`.

A consequent of it is that every object in `putObject` will eventually be reachable from `head`. That's because we are connecting after `tail`, and this node can be deleted only after we write the new node's reference to its `next`, which means the new node is reachable from `head`.

The added objects are trivially ordered by the `getAndSet` operation in `putObject`.

The dequeued objects are ordered according successful `compareAndSet` operations in `getObject`.

The `getObject`/`putObject` are ordered according to write/read to volatile field `next`.

Comment: How do you mean "you still retain its reference from head"? `head` is set to `nextNode` in that method.

Comment: I mean, the `value` that was in `nextNode` is returned and retained through `head`. If no more elements are taken from the queue (such as if the queue is empty afterwards), the reference to the returned value is never freed.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the memory leak issue, and made `next` volatile. But I don't yet understand why `value` needs to be volatile. Could you please explain further?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd get an NPE when you try to "release the value..." if you call

```
new LockFreeQueue<?>().getObject();
```

since you don't perform any nullity checks on `valueNode` there, despite guarding against it above.

Comment: You're right. I had missed that totally! I fixed it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the implementation of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html
It does pretty much what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out for more ideas. However, the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is too complex, as it supports many methods, while my queue is much simpler, which allows me to make more assumptions and try more optimizations.

Comment: There's an argument that lock-free code is complex by nature. ;)